Refresh/Reload MAUI Blazor Hybrid page
We have a SPA built with Blazor Hybrid MAUI. For various reason we would like that the user could refresh/reload the app to initial state, similarly to the Refresh/F5 feature in a regular browser. We tried having a button which calls this javascript:
location.reload();

That seems to work but it seems like that the memory consumption increases a lot for each refresh/reload so bit worrying. Wondering if anyone knows any good way of doing this?

What does the refresh/reload the app to initial state mean? Go to the root razor page and without any changes?

As close as possible to do a "refresh" - similar to pressing F5 on a regular browser.

The maui blazor runs on different platforms bases on the platform webview. You may need to call the platform native api to do that. In addition, you can also create new instance of the webview and set the source as the current route.

Any thoughts on how I can refresh rather than create a new webview instance? Seems like a not good solution.


That seems to work but it seems like that the memory consumption increases a lot for each refresh/reload so bit worrying

This is not matter. If you open the Task Manager and refresh the brower you will find the browser's memory consumption also increases a lot.
But you can also try to reload the current url in the webview to check the memory consumption.
In the MainPage.xaml:
<BlazorWebView x:Name="blazorWebView"/>

In the MainPage.cs:
        public void Reload(string url)
        {
#if Android
            var androidweb = blazorWebView.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Webkit.WebView;
            androidweb.LoadUrl(url);
#elif WINDOWS
            var windowweb = blazorWebView.Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView2;
            windowweb.Source = new Uri(url);
#elif IOS
            var iosweb = blazorWebView.Handler.PlatformView as WebKit.WKWebView;
            iosweb.LoadRequest(new Foundation.NSUrlRequest(new Uri(url)));
#endif
        }

And in the razor page:
@inject NavigationManager nav;

@code{
   public void Refresh()
   {  
      (App.Current.MainPage as MainPage).Reload(nav.Uri);
   }
}

